# request.method == 'POST' vs. request.is_ajax(). Mutually exclusive?

Tags: django

As the title says, I'm interested to know if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax() are mutually exclusive.

Thanks

Comment: No, an AJAX request can be a GET, POST, PUT, PATCH,... method See for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) how to make a POST call.

Comment: Thanks for your help!